# Convert double vector to single comma separated vector

Tags: r, tibble

I have a tibble:

```
example <-  tibble(Level = list(0.80,0.90)) %>%

                mutate(bounds = list(c(2.3,4.5),
                                     c(2.7,5.2)))
```

When I make a gt table,
I get a 2x2 tibble that looks something like this:

```
Level  Bounds
0.80   2.3, 4.5
0.90   2.7, 5.1
```

What I want is a 2x2 gt table that has only one element under bounds, in parenthesis:

```
Level  Bounds
0.80   (2.3,4.5)
0.90   (2.7,5.1)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` possibility could be:

```
example %>%
 transmute(Level_bounds = paste(unlist(Level),
                                paste0("(", map_chr(bounds, paste, collapse = ","), ")"),
                                sep = " - "))

  Level_bounds   
  <chr>          
1 0.8 - (2.3,4.5)
2 0.9 - (2.7,5.2)
```

If in fact two columns are needed:

```
example %>%
 transmute(Level = unlist(Level),
           bounds = paste0("(", map_chr(bounds, paste, collapse = ","), ")"))

  Level bounds   
  <dbl> <chr>    
1   0.8 (2.3,4.5)
2   0.9 (2.7,5.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `unnest` the `list` columns, grouped by 'Level', `paste` the 'elements in 'bounds' and format it with `sprintf`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
example %>%
    unnest %>% 
    group_by(new = Level) %>% 
    summarise(Level_Bounds = sprintf('%0.2f - (%s)',
             first(Level), toString(bounds))) %>%
    select(-new)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#  Level_Bounds     
#  <chr>            
#1 0.80 - (2.3, 4.5)
#2 0.90 - (2.7, 5.2)
```

If we need two columns

```
library(stringr)
example %>%
 unnest %>% 
  group_by(Level) %>% 
  summarise(Bounds = str_c("(", toString(bounds), ")"))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Level Bounds  
#   <dbl> <chr>   
# 1   0.8 (2.3, 4.5)
#2   0.9 (2.7, 5.2)
```

---

Or using `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
example %>% 
    transmute(Level_bounds = pmap_chr(., ~  paste0(..1, " - (",
           toString(..2), ")")))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#  Level_bounds    
#  <chr>           
#1 0.8 - (2.3, 4.5)
#2 0.9 - (2.7, 5.2)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
data.frame(Level = unlist(example$Level),
      Bounds = paste0("(", sapply(example$bounds, toString), ")"))
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can mutate a new variable that converts the double vector to a single vector with parenthesis using paste? That might be an easier solution and would also give me a 2x2 column, which is what I am trying to get.

My apologies, should have made that clear in the original question. Have edited it to reflect that now.